# Synchronise Renewals on existing subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

I have a site that uses woocommerce together with subscriptions plugin. And I have recently turned on "Synchronise Renewals", I see that it works great for new people signing up for a subscription. But the previous subscriptions are not renewing to the specific day, but is renewing on the same day they signed up..

How can i make my precious subscriptions renew on the same day?

Would a solution be to manually change the date in "Next payment" field in the Billing schedule box on each subscription? Will that make it renew every monday if the date is on a monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a solution for this is to manually change the date in "Next payment" field in the Billing schedule box on each subscription

A subscription can be unsynchronized by changing the next payment date to a day not aligned with the synchronization schedule. For example, changing a weekly subscription synchronized to Mondays to have the next payment processed on Wednesday will mean all future payments will be processed on Wednesday. This is because future payments are calculated based on the past payment and renewal synchronisation is only calculated and applied to the first payment.

Comment: Okay! And thanks for your answer! Just to be clear, if I set the next payment to 26 september (monday), woocommerce will then understand that 26:e is a monday and will charge next on 3 april which is monday?